# Workaround invalid checksum when using ETH Private Key to sign messages sent to contract

Tags: solidity, remix, keccak, checksum

I'm using an ETH private key to sign messages sent to a contract. I'm recovering the address from the signature inside the contract to verify the message (This actually took me days to piece together from what's available online). My problem is that when this pieced together code recovers the address from the signature **at runtime** it doesn't have the checksum. That is no problem for me, but the compiler won't let me store the non-checksummed address in the contract. I get the SyntaxError:

```
SyntaxError: This looks like an address but has an invalid checksum. Correct checksummed address: "0x...". If this is not used as an address, please prepend '00'
```

```
address signerPublic = 0x...;

Helper method:
  // Builds a prefixed hash to mimic the behavior of eth_sign.
  function prefixed(bytes32 hash) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash));
  }

Params:
   string memory tokenURI_;
   bytes memory signature;

In Method Body:
 
   bytes32 hashedURI = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(tokenURI_));   
   bytes32 prefixedHash = prefixed(hashedURI);      
   address signer = prefixedHash.recover(signature);

   if (signer == signerPublic) {...}
```

I actually had everything working, but when I switched from using Hardhat to deploy to using Remix to deploy it mysteriously fell apart.

Also if you have a better way to sign messages sent to a contract that would also solve my problem.

Edited for clarity based on comments.

Comment: You can just copy the checksummed address `0x...` and replace that with the current value of `signerPublic`.

Comment: Thank you, my question is a little long-winded and hard to follow. The code that I've pasted together here from what I could find online generates the non-checksummed address. So I need to match against a non-checksummed address.

Comment: The checksum is just the capitalisation of different characters. The actual value is still the same, so you can just compare both addresses. If you need to hardcode an address in your contract (like `signerPublic`) make sure to use the checksummed address. If that's not what you mean, please try to describe your problem in further detail.

Comment: Hi, thanks for engaging with me on this. Root cause: there is no well documented way to send a signed message to a contract. I'm almost there, but I need to recover the checksummed address not just the address.

Comment: @AaronSkomra Addresses' checksum only exists off-chain internaly on the EVM all addresses are just 20 bytes without checksum. New versions of the solidity compiler require addresses to have checksum, you can skip the checksum by using bytes20 instead but I won't recommend it, only use checksumed addresses on solidity.